# Check if user can write on a friend's Wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-wall

If there any way to check in PHP SDK if user can write on specific friend's Wall?

Example:

```
if ($facebook_can_write_to->'123456789') echo "You can write on this friend's Wall";
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the FQL table (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/) you can check to see if the current user can post to a friends wall by loading up the friend's user information specifically the `can_post` field.

**can_post**    *bool*  Whether or not the viewer can post to the user's Wall.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/) you can post on a user friends wall if that user granted you the *publish_stream* permission:

**publish_stream**

> Enables your app to post content, comments, and likes to a user's
>   stream and to the streams of the **user's friends**.

There are some cases in which you won't be able to do so, for example if some user blocked your application then I guess it will fail if you try, so you should just check the response you get back from facebook for the api request and see if it worked or not.

---

## Edit

As far as I'm aware you can not ask the api (nor via fql) "can my application post to this users wall", you can only ask "have this user granted my application the publish_stream permission".

If I understand what you want, I might have kind of a solution for you though.
I say show the user the option to post on a friends wall.
When the user chooses this option try to post on the friends wall (and I assume you are using ajax for that call), if it fails return some kind of code, then in the client side check for that code, if it returns use the javascript sdk to open a dialog.

You have two choices for dialogs, you can use the [Feed Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) like this:

```
var obj = {
    method: 'feed',
    to: "FRIEND_ID",
    name: 'A message',
    caption: 'Just trying something',
    description: 'This is how to post on a friends wall'
};

FB.ui(obj, function(response) { console.log(response); });
```

Or you can use the [Send Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/):

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'send',
    to: "FRIEND_ID",
    name: 'A message',
    link: 'LINK_URL',
});
```

With this one though you have to post a link, I'm not sure if that works for you. After you tried and failed for a user you can save that data and use it later.

Comment: That's true but that is not the problem, the problem is if user has disable ability for friends to write on his wall. So even with this permission you can't write on someones wall and this is why I need to check in PHP if I normally can write to users wall and if not then I do not offer this option to user.

Comment: I edited my original answer with a response, to do with php is not possible as far as I know.